# auth_redirect() doesn't send users to the page where they orginally tried to acces

Tags: filters, redirect, template-redirect

In the site I am building, I'm using "theme my plugin" so I could make my own login, logout, registration pages.

For the login form, I used the default `wp_login_form` input names, and the default value for the hidden type input named `redirect_to` which is:  `( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` .

for some pages, I want user to login to access to them, so I use `the auth_redirect()` function, as expected it sends users to the login page, but after login, doesn't send them back to the page they were originally.

So I tried to filter the `login_redirect`... but it doesn't work. Thanks for your help!

```php
function my_login_redirect_function(){
    if(( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == get_bloginfo('url').'/login'){
            return get_bloginfo('url').'/dashboard';
        }else{
            $urlStartPos= strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http');
            return(urldecode($urlStartPos)); 
        }
add_filter('login_redirect','my_login_redirect_function');
```

Comment: What is "theme my plugin"?

Comment: it's a plugin... sorry, I made a mistake in the name, it's "theme my login". Its purpose is to replace default wordpress link for login, logout, register, lost password etc...

Comment: hmm normally WP would use a `redirect_to` get parameter, but there's nothing here that reads that, and it's unclear how this plugin is meant to handle the redirect. Have you asked theme my login support? 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here, and what would work in normal WP may not work for you, any answer you get here may not apply to theme my login